# How to tell the number of defective tablets using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm working on a project, where I have to display the number of defected tablets. Till now I'm done with the preprocessing like:

1. rgb2gray
2. gray to binary image
3. bwmorph (erode and remove)

And after all these operations, I'm left with this output.

[image]

Here one defective tablet is there. And I wanted to know how to display that this blister contain a defect.

Here's a section of my code which tells the difference between the ideal blister and the defective one.

```
% Calculate the Normalized Histogram of Image 1 and Image 2
hn1 = imhist(Imageg1)./numel(Imageg1); 
hn2 = imhist(Imageg2)./numel(Imageg2); 

% Calculate the histogram error/ Difference
f1 = sum((hn1 - hn2).^2); 

set(handles.text3,'String',f1)

if sum( abs( I1(:) - I2(:) ) ) == 0.0
      h=msgbox(' No Defect Found');
else
      h=msgbox(' Defect Found');
end
```

This is the original blister(unprocessed)

[image]

This is the ideal blister 
[image]

Is there any way I can tell how many tablets are defective?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like the defect has a much smaller closed component size. This might be something you can check against.

Comment: Can you provide the original/unprocessed image?

Comment: Is it ok if instead you automatically find how many tablets don't have a defect?

Comment: Looks to me like a problem for Support Vector Machines. The "only" thing to do is extracting some nice features. Maybe do line extraction or take the differential of the pixel intensities.

Comment: If we can see the original unprocessed image, it would provide us with better insight on how to tackle your problem.  The image that you have provided goes through some processing steps that not all of us may agree to, and so providing the unprocessed image allows us freedom to determine the best chain of steps to be able to automatically detect which pills are defective.  However, I agree with potAito that you should probably lean more towards doing this as a supervised learning approach more than an image processing based approach.

Comment: @Benoit_11 That will be fine. Can you tell me a way to find the number of tablets don't have defect.

Comment: @rayryeng Sir, I have updated my question. Can you tell me what I have to do now? Do I need to change the processing for a better result?

Comment: I'll provide an answer soon. I've been very busy.

Answer (score 0):

Given a known 'good' blisterpack, can you extract the subregions of a sample image relating to each blister? If so, you then simply need a blister evaluator function and that's a lot easier to deal with than the entire image.

For each candidate blister you:

1. Grayscale
2. Canny edge detect
3. Extract contours
4. Compare contour area (or height) to known good area (or height) and reject those below a particular percentage.

If you can't easily code the segmentation of sisters directly (i.e. hard code numbers), you can calculate horizontal and vertical histograms of the Canny output and extract peaks to find the bounds of the blisters in X and Y directions